# How do I copy heads on minecraft on a windows 10 laptop?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I've see people do it with ctrl scroll (or pick block) but I seem to not be able to do it. Others use command scroll, but I've tried and came out with just a steve head that when you go into your inventory, says its NBT, which I don't know what that means. :/ All I need is a little hint or tip to do it on a laptop, not a mac.

Comment: When it says "+NBT" in the tooltip, the head data *should* be copied correctly. Can you post (a) screenshot(s) of the head you want to copy, the head in your inventory and the tooltip? [edit] them into the question.

Answer (score 2):

1) If you want are use a touchpad instead of a mouse, change `Pick block` from `Button 3` to another key.

**2) Are you playing on a server? If so, I think Spigot does not fully support picking blocks with NBT data yet. I am using a Spigot server and I can't do that either.**

3) Not really sure about this one, but if you are not connected to the internet and the player head in question in not in your cache, it might just be that Minecraft can't load the skin. (Very unlikely)